# Geodesic lines in Poincare disc model

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

There is Poincare disc model with metric
$g=4\dfrac{dx^2+dy^2}{(4-x^2-y^2)^2}$
I have to find geodesic lines in this model. I tried with system of differential equation, but it is very complicated.
I have:

$ (\frac{x'}{(4-x^2-y^2)^2})' -2x\frac{(x')^2+(y')^2}{(4-x^2-y^2)^3} = 0$

$ (\frac{y'}{(4-x^2-y^2)^2})' -2y\frac{(x')^2+(y')^2}{(4-x^2-y^2)^3} = 0$

Also, I tried polar coordinates, but still nothing

Comment: There are some obvious ones. Then apply isometries to them to find the others.

Comment: I think this might be easier to do in the upper half plane model. Then use an isometry from the upper half space to the disk to map the geodesics to the disk.

Comment: You have a typo in the metric.